# Bootstrap Fixed Navigation float line and text over

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

Bear with me.

So I have a standard navigation with the minor change that it is set to 150px tall in the css so the larger logo will fit in it on the left where "brand" usually is in the demos.

What I would like to do is something like this - The last three items are all services. I don't really want a drop down so I'd like to have
 
----------------------Services---------------------- 
Assesments Improvements Incident Response 
above it. Normally I'd work all that out on the page with a div but in this case I can't figure out how to add it to the UL for the menu.

Any idea how to do that maybe with a :before or something?

HTML:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="topFixedNavbar1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="news-resources.html">News</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Assessments</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Improvements</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Incident Response</a></li>


        </ul>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much can insert a `div` if you want: maybe this will help you get started.

`Navbar-collapse` is split between two separate `navbar-nav` elements with the new `services` class inside the second, above your second set of links.

```css
body,
html {
  margin-top: 175px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #444;
}
.navbar-custom .services {
  color: #444;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -25px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
  margin-top: 45px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-right .navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-size: 12px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-custom .services {
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-toggle,
  .navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 55px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border: none;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-right .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#topFixedNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x115/444/fff?text=Logo">
      </a>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="topFixedNavbar1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">About</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="news-resources.html">News</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <div class="services">Services</div>
        <li><a href="#">Assessments</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Improvements</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Incident</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well wel-lg">Some Junk</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in returning, got very sick for a few days there. lol

This definitely points me in the right direction. I'll have to play with the placement of the full screen elements as they are all supposed to come from the right side of the screen. 

Thanks for the help!

Comment: All right, so using your code works great except that the three menu items above where the div is in the code are up against the logo rather than in line with the rest of the menu items. I tried inserting the DIV into one UL which didn't work properly as I guessed. Unsure where to go with it next, can you assist further?

Comment: One question out of curiosity: do the links all need to be on the same line or can the "Services" and standard links be stacked over one another?

Comment: I updated it with the links all floated to the right.

Comment: Of course when I'm away from desk. Lol Thank you! Will check it out soon.

Comment: It happens and no problem!

Comment: Excellent! Everything looks great, really appreciate it.

Comment: Just for reference, I'm trying to rebuild a wordpress site that used a very strange template system for all the pages even though there  were no posts on most of them, just static content. So the site loaded very slowly. I decided to move all of it out to static html and have just the one page that actually had updates to remain in the framework.